# How to change speed of Entities?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

How can I change the speed of entities in `Minecraft` using plugins?  I just recently started making `plugins` for `Minecraft`, so I will be very grateful if you can help me (I use `spigot`)

Comment: Maybe it's trivial, but have you considered using speed-potions? ^^

Comment: no, i will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This forum post](https://bukkit.org/threads/how-could-i-change-an-entitys-walking-speed.396471/) may solve your problem. A dude asked the same question as you and gave some code snippets to help.

```
private static final UUID movementSpeedUID = UUID.fromString("206a89dc-ae78-4c4d-b42c-3b31db3f5a7c");
   
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.MONITOR, ignoreCancelled = true)
    public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
        LivingEntity entity = (LivingEntity) event.getEntity();
       
        if (!(event.getDamager() instanceof Arrow)) return;
        Arrow arrow = (Arrow) event.getDamager();
        if (arrow.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
            EntityInsentient nmsEntity = (EntityInsentient) ((CraftLivingEntity) entity).getHandle();
            AttributeInstance attributes = nmsEntity.getAttributeInstance(GenericAttributes.MOVEMENT_SPEED);
           
            AttributeModifier modifier = new AttributeModifier(movementSpeedUID, "movement speed multiplier", 1.0d, 1);
           
            attributes.b(modifier);
        }
    }
```

I wish I could help more, but I still haven't learned Java. I hope to, soon. I literally have a book on my bookshelf teaching Java, but I just haven't had the time.

Comment: Umm, are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the walk speed of the player by

```
CommandSender sender;
Player player = (Player) sender;
player.setWalkSpeed(2);
```

Or

```
  public void setWalkSpeed(double speed) {
    CommandSender sender;
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if (speed > 10) {
        double b = speed - 10;
        speed -= b;
    }
    if (speed < 0) {
        speed -= speed;
    }
    double a = speed / 10;
    float value = (float) a;
    player.setWalkSpeed(value);
}
```

And then call the method setWalkSpeed() in your command.